# Can c# pull DNS Host record Security permissions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dns

I have been asked to see if I can read DNS Host records (A records) and produce a report showing what accounts have what security permissions. I have searched high and low and the closest I could find was the *Bdev.Net.Dns* project but unfortunately this does not do permissions.

I am not even sure if it can be done.  I have done this before with actual file permissions but never messed with DNS.  Since my search has been futile, does anyone even know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Geo...

Comment: Are the DNS records in a particular DNS server, or are you trying to do this for an arbitrary host name?

Comment: Yes they are in a particular DNS server.

Comment: And, what DNS server are you using?  Windows Server?  BIND? What version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Key was to find the right distinguishedName for the object wanted.  Key was this:  CN=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones

Then, access like any other AD object.

```
objDNSRecord = GetObject("LDAP://DC=" & strComputer & "," & sPath)
        objNtSecurityDescriptor = objDNSRecord.Get("ntSecurityDescriptor")
        DACL = objNtSecurityDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl
```